# Laravel Datatables: How to sort column with the second data

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable, laravel-datatables

How do I sort according to the second data? The sorting works only on the ID. But in my table, I added a badge count and that's what I want to sort by.

Here is my controller

```php
    return DataTables::of($users)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('Inventories', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                return '<a href="'.route('admin.clients.show-client-inventories2', $row->id).'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'.__("Inventories").' <span class="right badge badge-success" title="Total Lost">'.(abs($row->inv_total_lost_qty) ?? 'N/A').'</span> </a>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('Returns', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                return ' <a href="'.route('admin.clients.show-client-returns', $row->id) .'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'.__('Returns').' <span class="right badge badge-warning" title="Total Returns">'.(abs($row->overall_returns_count) ?? 'N/A').'</span> </a>';
            }
            $row->status->orderBy(abs($row->overall_returns_count));
        })
        ->addColumn('inbound_shipments', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                return '<a href="'. route('admin.clients.show-client-inbound-shipments', $row->id).'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'. __('Inbound Shipments').'<span class="right badge badge-danger" title="Total Overcharged Fees">'. abs($row->shipment_quantity_diff).'</span> </a>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('overcharged', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                return '<a href="'. route('admin.clients.show-client-overcharged-fee', $row->id).'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'.__('Overcharged Fee') .' <span class="right badge badge-primary" title="Total Overcharged Fees">'.(abs($row->overall_overcharged_fees_count) ?? 'N/A').'</span> </a>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('ALL', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                $arr = array(abs($row->overall_overcharged_fees_count), abs($row->overall_returns_count), abs($row->inv_total_lost_qty),abs($row->shipment_quantity_diff));
                return array_sum($arr);
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('credentials', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                return '<button onclick="set_credentials(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> '.__("Set Credentials").'</button>';
            }
        })
        ->addColumn('reim', function ($row) {
            if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
                return '<a href="'. route('admin.clients.show-client-reimbursements', $row->id).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">'.__('Reimbursements') .'</a>';
            }
          
        })
        ->rawColumns(['Inventories','action','Returns','inbound_shipments','overcharged','ALL','credentials','reim'])
        ->make(true);
}

return view('admin.clients.index', compact('users'));
```

The column I want to sort is not `$row->id`, what I want is the second one like `abs($row->overall_returns_count)`.

And in my Blade code. I wrote something like this:

```js
//Update start
{width: "10%", data: 'ALL', name: 'ALL', orderable: true, searchable: false},
{width: "10%", data: 'Inventories', name: 'Inventories', orderable: true, searchable: false},
{width: "10%", data: 'Returns', name: 'Returns', orderable: true, searchable: false},
{width: "15%", data: 'inbound_shipments', name: 'Inbound Shipments', orderable: true, searchable: false},
{width: "10%", data: 'overcharged', name: 'Overchared Fee', orderable: true, searchable: false},
```

[image]

As you can see, if I click the header, it doesn't sort the badge. Instead, it sorts the `id` as you can see in the lower left corner when I hovered the button. (id starting in 2)

System details
Operating System Windows 10

PHP Version 7.2

Laravel Version 6.0

Laravel-Datatables Version ^9.6

Comment: `$users` is a query builder or a collection?

Comment: Have you already considered, that your named route might be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this is because of the big red notification at the top of [DataTables manual](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/add-column)? ``Added columns are assumed to be computed columns and not part of the database. Thus, search/sort will be disabled on those columns. If you need them, use the editColumn api instead.`` It might be easier if you use the official documentation' [example of sorting by multiple columns](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/order-columns).

Comment: tried it but still not working @DanielProtopopov

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding data-order attribute in row as below

```
if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
    return ' <a href="'.route('admin.clients.show-client-returns', $row->id) .'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'.__('Returns').' <span class="right badge badge-warning" data-order = '.abs($row->overall_returns_count) ?? '0'.' title="Total Returns">'.(abs($row->overall_returns_count) ?? 'N/A').'</span> </a>';
  }
```

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: It will sort column by that attribute value

Comment: its still the same sir

Comment: inspect the row and check whether you are getting count values in data-order attribute

Comment: yes im getting count values but it does not sort. can you help me further in this problem?

Comment: i think I got it now. THanks for the help. data-order is the answer

Answer (score 3):

What is your data source? if your data source is laravel collection, you should render on the JavaScript when init datatable using `render: function (data, action, row)`. Should be like:

```
{
    width: "10%", data: 'overall_returns_count', name: 'overall_returns_count', orderable: true, searchable: false,
    render: function (data, action, row) {
        if (row.status != 'Dumped2') {
            return ' <a href="/admin/client/' + row.id + '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">' +
                'Returns <span class="right badge badge-warning" title="Total Returns">' + (Math.abs(data)) +
                '</span> </a>';
        }
    },
},
```

If your data source is  query builder, you can render using PHP, but you should use `editColumn`  instead of`addColumn`. example:

```
    ->editColumn('overall_returns_count', function ($row) {
        if($row->status != 'Dumped2') {
            return ' <a href="'.route('admin.clients.show-client-returns', $row->id) .'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'.__('Returns').' <span class="right badge badge-warning" title="Total Returns">'.(abs($row->overall_returns_count) ?? 'N/A').'</span> </a>';
        }
        $row->status->orderBy(abs($row->overall_returns_count));
    })
```

then in js columns :

```
{width: "10%", data: 'overall_returns_count', name: 'overall_returns_count', orderable: true, searchable: false},
```

PHP render works only if you are using eloquent/DB query builder as data source , but JS render
works on all data source including Laravel Collection and eloquent builder.

Just for your information, [Yajra Datatable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) is support multiple data source including Collection and Query Builder. Sometime if you use Collection as data source will make slow perfomance and some feature look messy, so I recommend you using Query Builder as data source.

this will return Collection :

```
$users = User::withCount('overall_returns')->get();
```

this will return Query Builder:

```
$users = User::withCount('overall_returns');
```

Comment: So i can now sort the badges by using this? Not the id?

Comment: sort based on the column, in your case `overall_returns_count`

Comment: I tested and both options(JS and PHP render) is worked. but the column should from select query like `select('column_name')` or `withCount`, not from custom model attribute.

Comment: Its working but it only returns a string. the button and the badge is not showing. I followed the second option sir also it returns an html string if i modify

Comment: Oh I forgot the last thing, add it on the rawColumns,  `->rawColumns(['overall_returns_count'])`

Comment: its still, it cannot sort the badge. instad it sorts the `$row->id`

Comment: I think the problem is your `overall_returns_count`, what is that? from column or what?

Comment: From column sir

Comment: what I need to sort is `$row->overall_returns_count` not the `$row->id` i think its impossible?